# Theming menu--main.html.twig to Foundation 6 Top Bar responsive menu

Tags: theming, 8

How do I have to change `menu--main.html.twig` to get [Foundation Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html) working?

This is what I have so far in `menu--main.html.twig`:

```
  <div class="top-bar">

    <div class="top-bar-title">
      <span data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
        <button class="menu-icon dark" type="button" data-toggle></button>
      </span>
      <strong>Site Title</strong>
    </div>

    <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">

      <div class="top-bar-left">
        {{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'vertical', 'medium-horizontal').setAttribute('data-responsive-menu') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

But it's always showing the toggle button? Do I have to activate any javascript for the Responsive menu and the Top Bar?

Comment: Please give this a bit of effort on your part, Drupal Answers is not a service where you can get a feature developed. What have you done? Where are you struggling, try to be more concrete.

Comment: @googletorp ok I changed and edit my question.

Comment: @googletorp why it's still on hold?